# 'development' database is not configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am getting this error while doing `rake db:migrate` of newly cloned app.

'development' database is not configured. Available: ["production"]

So after reading the error, I am doing `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`

But this isn't working either.

My `database.yml` has

```
production:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: test
pool: 5
username: admin
password: admin
port: 5433
```

Please suggest.

Comment: this ain't valid yaml. yaml needs to be indented by 2 whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: test
  pool: 5
  username: admin
  password: admin
  port: 5433
  host: localhost
```

to `database.yml` file.

Also, if you test your application, you'll need `test` environment as well.

Comment: rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory


This is what I am getting.

Comment: already tried adding localhost.
`rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5433?`


the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `database.yml` file shows you have only production environment configured for DB operations. You need to add configuration for development environment as well.

Open your `database.yml` file and add a configuration for development environment. 
Something like the following should suffice (contents in square brackets are to be replaced with your actual values):

```
development:
    adapter:[your adapter]
    encoding: [your encoding]
    database: [your database for development]
    pool: [your pool]
    username: [your database server username]
    password: [your database server password]
    port: [the port you're connecting on]
```

Remember to indent your **yaml** code appropriately.